# Why does mouse cursor disappear when using stylus to click and drag? how to prevent?

Tags: javascript, html

When I use a stylus to click and drag, it hides the cursor.
How would I prevent the cursor from hiding via code?

I have a drawing app, that uses a crosshair cursor to show where you are drawing. However, using a stylus causes it to disappear. I can't find any solution to this.

```
    div.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){
        if(e.type == 'touchmove'){
            if (e.preventDefault) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            e.returnValue = false;
            return false;
        }
    }, { passive:false });
```

Comment: Can you include some code?

Comment: added some code
however, the effect is seen on any webpage.. when you click and drag with stylus the cursor disappears. I need to prevent that in my app.

Comment: I can't help: never seen any stylus on a web page